# How to enable DELETE request?

Tags: express, cors

I'm not able to allow the `DELETE` request from my API server due to CORS.

#### server.js

```
// enable CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});
```

I get a console error saying:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/users/57f5036645c04700128d4ee0. Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response`

How can I enable `DELETE` requests, just like `GET`, `PUT`, and `POST` requests?

Comment: @UmakantMane I updated my frontend request like so: `$.ajax({ async: true, crossDomain: true, url: '...', method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': '...' } });`, but that didn't help

Comment: @UmakantMane Post a comment instead of suggestion

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved it without adding new packages, just added this line

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
```

Notice that i have my allowed methods separated by commas inside one string.
The complete function looks like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

One of your headers is not properly set, so instead of

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
```

put it as

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

But you're right, using the npm package is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by simply using npm's [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests) package and enabling all cors requests, by simply replacing...

```
// enable CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});
```

with...

```
app.use(require('cors')());
```

But I'm still not sure what magic cors package is doing under the hood to make it work.