# Getting 404 (Not Found) on axios.delete()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I'm trying to implement the delete functionality for my survey creation app.

I'm using MongoDB with mongoose for the database, node.js/Express for the backend server and React/Redux for the frontend side.

Although I think I set routing correctly, I get 404 (Not Found) on axios.delete().

The error says that `http://localhost:3000/api/surveys/delete/{the-survey-id-here}` is not found.

I have been reading the documentation of axios, Express, mongoose and other websites, however, nothing worked for me.

I tried the following things.

- Use findByIdAndRemove() instead of deleteOne()
- Pass `surveyId` in the action creator `const response = await axios.delete("/api/surveys", data: { surveyId });`
- Use `<a></a>` instead of `<button></button>`

Here are my codes.

SurveyList.js (react component which has the delete button)

```
import { fetchSurveys, deleteSurvey } from '../../actions'

...

<div className="card-action">
  <a className="red-text text-accent-1">Yes: {survey.yes}</a>
  <a className="red-text text-accent-1">No: {survey.no}</a>
  <button
    className="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red right"
    onClick={() => this.props.deleteSurvey(survey._id)}
  >
    <i className="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
  </button>
</div>

...

const mapStateToProps = ({ surveys }) => {
  return { surveys }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchSurveys, deleteSurvey }
)(SurveyList)
```

actions/index.js (action creator)

```
export const deleteSurvey = (surveyId) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.delete(`/api/surveys/delete/${surveyId}`)

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_SURVEYS, payload: response.data })
}
```

surveyRoute.js (routing handler)

```
app.delete('/api/surveys/delete/:surveyId', async (req, res) => {
  await Survey.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.surveyId })

  const surveys = await Survey.find({ _user: req.user.id }).select({
    recipients: false
  })
  res.send(surveys)
})
```

server/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const keys = require('./config/keys')
require('./models/User')
require('./models/Survey')
require('./services/passport')

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI)

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // milliseconds
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/billingRoutes')(app)
require('./routes/surveyRoutes')(app)

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  const path = require('path')
  app.get('*',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT)
```

Comment: show your main `app.js`, where you're using `surveyRoute.js`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the main routing file at the bottom.

Comment: serving on port 3000 or 5000? what is you env.PORT value?

Comment: env.PORT is passed from Heroku. Otherwise, `npm run server` will use 5000 and `npm run client` will use 3000.

Comment: You say `client` runs on 3000 and `server` runs on 5000, but you're making request to port 3000, meaning the client?

Comment: you should try replacing 5000 port with 3000 `app.listen(3000)`

Comment: Thank you for all comments here. It turned out the problem was the way of setting the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

```
In my case, leads/ is the end point. try your end point + survey id
With axios@^0.19.2

       axios
            .delete('/api/leads/' + id)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: DELETE_LEAD,
                    payload: id
                });
```

Comment: please, add necessary explanation

Answer (score 0):

So if I undestood correctly, you have a Expressjs App and a client app running on different ports, if so I think I found the issue

You are making ajax calls as if you had both frontend and backend running on the same server. Here are two possible solutions

1. Change the address of the Axios delete action to point to the right server if you are planning to run the backend and frontend on different servers

   ```
   app.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/surveys/delete/:surveyId', async (req, res) => {
     await Survey.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.surveyId })

     const surveys = await Survey.find({ _user: req.user.id }).select({
       recipients: false
     })
     res.send(surveys)
   })
   ```

   Off course you have to change the address once you deploy it to production and enable CORS
2. Build the client app for producion, this process will compile all css, js and html and save it to client/build folder as stated on line

   ```
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
   ```

   This will cause the frontend and backend code to run on the same server

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It made me realize that there might be a problem with the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all answers and comments. The problem was the proxy. I am using `http-proxy-middleware` to handle requests between different ports in the dev environment. All comments about ports made me realize that I need to check the 'setupProxy.js' file. I modified the code inside the file as below and that fixed the problem.

setupProxy.js

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy ('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
  app.use(proxy ('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
}
```

Thank you very much again for all the answers and comments.

Answer (score -2):

CORS (Delete verb) must be enabled in your route middleware.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876110/how-to-enable-delete-request) thread may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was the proxy. It didn't handle the request properly.