# Why is it showing DELETE /api/product/productId 404

Tags: reactjs

```
const handleDelete = (productsId, productsProductName)=>{
        setSuccessMessage('')
        setErrorMessage('')
        axios.delete('/api/products/'+productsId)
        .then(response =>{
            if(response.data != null){
                setSuccessMessage(`${productsProductName} deleted successfully`)
                this.setState({
                    productsData : this.state.productsData.filter(products => products.id !== productsId)
                })
            }
        })
```

<Button target="_blank" onClick={handleDelete.bind(this, p._id)}> Delete

Comment: 404 is coming from the server-side, did you check if the product exists in your database?

Comment: it already exists in the database

Comment: are you using any proxy or middleware on your application? e.g(http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: it shows DELETE /api/products/600aa7cf43500f29306df850 404 0.443 ms - 180

Comment: i haven't used any proxy

Comment: is it correct :600aa7cf43500f29306df850 product id?. Because I see : before product Id.

Comment: no : is added type mistake

Comment: by the way this is an onclick event

Answer (score 0):

It could be a proxy issue.
Try to update `setupProxy.js` as your need.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy ('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
  app.use(proxy ('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
}
```

Here is the similar problem reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404279/getting-404-not-found-on-axios-delete)

Comment: but post and get requests are working fine