# Firebase authorization bearer token not registering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

Error message: No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header. Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header: Authorizaiton: Bearer  or by passing a "__session" cookie

There actually is a valid token. This same setup works in other functions but not here. The main difference is that this is a delete instead of a post.

```
    firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then((token) => {
        console.log(token)
        return axios.delete(
          `${FunctionsDir}/deleteMessage`,
          {
            messageID: messageID,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
            },
          }
        )
      })
```

and the cors setup...

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
  methods: 'GET,POST,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}

app.options('*', cors())
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Update: Fixed, turned out to be the cors thing plus the axios.delete() sig was wrong.

Comment: Can you include your server-side code in your question. It is likely an issue with your CORS configuration.

Comment: Added CORS configuration.

Comment: You should post where you inject your `cors` middleware too - it's important to see how it's being used. e.g. Normally `app.options("*", cors())` or `app.options("/deleteMessage", cors())` must be present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue that needs to be solved on the server.

This is because DELETE requests need to make a pre-flight request to the server asking what is acceptable to send. Because you got a response from your server, it is likely that you have already added `DELETE` to your [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header. However, `Authorization` isn't considered a "safe header" by default. So you must also explicitly allow it, otherwise browsers will remove it from the request as they send it off. You can do this by adding `Authorization` to your [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) header.

If you are using Express on your server, you can allow the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package to do this for you:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.options("/deleteMessage", cors()); // enable preflight request for DELETE
app.use(cors({ origin: ["https://yourapp.com"] })); // enable CORS for all routes

// ...
```

If you don't like making use of third-party dependencies, you can manually add the headers as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43417702/3068190).

For non-express requests, like a HTTP Request Cloud Function, you can use the following code:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";

const corsMiddleware = cors({ origin: ["https://yourapp.com"] }); // or your manual (req, res, next) function

export const someFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  corsMiddleware(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send('CORS check failed');
      return;
    }

    // your code here
  }
})
```